# How to get vendor details in order-details.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Like is mentionned on the title, i would to know how to get vendor details into the order-details.php in WooCommerce?

Comment: what plugin are you using to have your vendor details?

Comment: There is no plugin just i use a template called DOKAN included already the vendor details, so i would to get it in my order details thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$store_user_ID` with the id of the store author, you'll get the info in the `$store_info` variable.

```
$store_info = dokan_get_store_info( $store_user_ID );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i try your code but no result given, on my order-details.php there isn't a $store user_ID that's why i would to get it for showing the consumer the vendor details.

Comment: i'm  trying to put this code but always no result; the code below copied from seller.php                                         <address>
<?php if ( isset( $store_info['address'] ) ) {
$address = esc_html( $store_info['address'] );
echo nl2br( $address );} ?>
<?php if ( isset( $store_info['phone'] ) && !empty( $store_info['phone'] ) ) { ?>
<abbr title="<?php _e( 'Phone', 'dokan' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'P:', 'dokan' ); ?></abbr> <?php echo esc_html( $store_info['phone'] ); ?>
 <?php } ?>
</address>